# Multiple Selection in UITableView Editing - with Maximum two Rows selection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am having a `UITableView` where selection leads to a detail view. I have a `BarbuttonItem` called **Compare** that enables Editing mode (multiple editing checked in Storyboard).

I want the user to be able to exactly select two entries (when two are selected, another OK-button will be available, otherwise only the Cancel Button will be enabled).

I was able to enable the OK-Button based on the amount of selected rows but how can I **disable** the selection when two are already selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows.count == 2 && ![tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows containsObject:indexPath]) {
    return nil;
  }

  return indexPath;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  return ([self tableView:tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] != nil);
}
```

**explanation:**

first of all you should do the check in willSelectRow (BEFORE selection) instead of didSelectRow (AFTER selection).
you check if the maximum is reached...

```
if (tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows.count == 2
```

and if the maximum is reached you have to do another check to make DESELECTION of a cell work:

```
&& ![tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows containsObject:indexPath])
```

if the maximum is reached and the currently selected row isn't already selected you simply

```
return nil;
```

you should also implement the shouldHighlighRow method to handle that

> gets selected but unselected a millisecond later

behaviour you do not want. hope i got you right :)

Answer (score 2):

In didselectRowAtIndexPath: check selectedEntries count and if it is 2 then use following code:-

```
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
return;
```

Comment: If I do it this way I can see how it gets selected but unselected a millisecond later... is it possible to "not see" the Selection at all?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build this logic in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method. Keep track of number of already selected cells and if its 2 do not execute the code further.